# Ember Understand execution flow between route/controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js, ember-cli, rsvp-promise

I have a "box" route/controller as below;

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    initialized: false,
    type: 'P',
    status: 'done',
    layouts: null,
    toggleFltr: null,
    gridVals: Ember.computed.alias('model.gridParas'),
    gridParas: Ember.computed('myServerPars', function() {
        this.set('gridVals.serverParas', this.get('myServerPars'));
        this.filterCols();

        if (!this.get('initialized')) {
            this.toggleProperty('initialized');
        } else {
            Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.refreshBox);
        }

        return this.get('gridVals');
    }),
    filterCols: function()
    {
        this.set('gridVals.layout', this.get('layouts')[this.get('type')]);
    },
    myServerPars: function() {
        // Code to set serverParas
        return serverParas;
    }.property('type', 'status', 'toggleFltr'),
    refreshBox: function(){
        // Code to trigger refresh grid
    }
});
```

My route looks like;

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    selectedRows: '',
    selectedCount: 0,
    rawResponse: {},
    model: function() {
        var compObj = {};
        compObj.gridParas = this.get('gridParas');
        return compObj;
    },
    activate: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.layouts = {};

        var someData = {attr1:"I"};
        var promise = this.doPost(someData, '/myService1', false); // Sync request (Is there some way I can make this work using "async")
        promise.then(function(response) {       
            // Code to use response & set self.layouts
            self.controllerFor(self.routeName).set('layouts', self.layouts);
        });
    },
    gridParas: function() {
        var self = this;
        var returnObj = {};
        returnObj.url = '/myService2';
        returnObj.beforeLoadComplete = function(records) {          
            // Code to use response & set records
            return records;
        };
        return returnObj;
    }.property(),   
    actions: {      
    }
});
```

My template looks like

```
{{my-grid params=this.gridParas elementId='myGrid'}}
```

My doPost method looks like below;

```
doPost: function(postData, requestUrl, isAsync){
    requestUrl = this.getURL(requestUrl);
    isAsync = (isAsync == undefined) ? true : isAsync;
    var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        return $.ajax({
            // settings
        }).success(resolve).error(reject);

    });
    return promise;
  }
```

Given the above setup, I wanted to understand the flow/sequence of execution (i.e. for the different hooks). 
I was trying to debug and it kept hopping from one class to another.
Also, 2 specific questions;

> 1. I was expecting the "activate" hook to be fired initially, but found out that is not the case. It first executes the "gridParas" hook
>      i.e. before the "activate" hook. Is it because of "gridParas"
>      specified in the template ?
> 2. When I do this.doPost() for /myService1, it has to be a "sync" request, else the flow of execution changes and I get an error.
>      Actually I want the code inside filterCols() controller i.e.
>      this.set('gridVals.layout', this.get('layouts')[this.get('type')]) to
>      be executed only after the response has been received from
>      /myService1. However, as of now, I have to use a "sync" request to do
>      that, otherwise with "async", the execution moves to filterCols() and
>      since I do not have the response yet, it throws an error.

Just to add, I am using Ember v 2.0

Answer (score 2):

1. `activate()` on the route is triggered *after* the `beforeModel`, `model` and `afterModel` hooks... because those 3 hooks are considered the "validation phase" (which determines if the route will resolve at all). To be clear, this route hook has nothing to do with using `gridParas` in your template... it has everything to do with callling `get('gridParas')` within your model hook.
2. It is not clear to me where `doPost()` is connected to the rest of your code... however because it is returning a `promise` object you can tack on a `then()` which will allow you to essentially wait for the promise response and then use it in the rest of your code.

Simple Example:

```
this.doPost().then((theResponse) => {
  this.doSomethingWith(theResponse);
});
```

If you can simplify your question to be more clear and concise, i may be able to provide more info

Comment: Thx for the response...For the doPost() part...there are essentially 2 AJAX calls being made..first one is to /myService1 (wrapped inside my custom promise implementation method) and 2nd one /myService2 (which is actually made by my custom component when I say returnObj.url = '/myService2' )

I want these to work in the following sequence;
1. Call to /myService1
2. Then after response from 1, call to /myService2
3. Then control should go to controller and grid should populate (i.e. following code to be executed...this.set('gridVals.layout', this.get('layouts')[this.get('type')]);)

Answer (score 0):

Generally at this level you should explain what you want to archive, and not just ask how it works, because I think you fight a lot against the framework!

But I take this out of your comment.

First, you don't need your doPost method! jQuerys `$.ajax` returns a thenable, that can be resolved to a Promise with `Ember.RSVP.resolve`!

Next: If you want to fetch data before actually rendering anything you should do this in the `model` hook!

I'm not sure if you want to fetch `/service1`, and then with the response you build a request to `/service2`, or if you can fetch both services independently and then show your data (your grid?) with the data of both services. So here are both ways:

---

If you can fetch both services independently do this in your routes `model` hook:

```
return Ember.RSVP.hash({
  service1: Ember.RSVP.resolve($.ajax(/*your request to /service1 with all data and params, may use query-params!*/).then(data => {
    return data; // extract the data you need, may transform the response, etc.
  },
  service2: Ember.RSVP.resolve($.ajax(/*your request to /service2 with all data and params, may use query-params!*/).then(data => {
    return data; // extract the data you need, may transform the response, etc.
  },
});
```

If you need the response of `/service1` to fetch `/service2` just do this in your model hook:

```
return Ember.RSVP.resolve($.ajax(/*/service1*/)).then(service1 => {
  return Ember.RSVP.resolve($.ajax(/*/service2*/)).then(service2 => {
    return {
      service1,
      service2
    }; // this object will then be available as `model` on your controller
  });
});
```

If this does not help you (and I really think this should fix your problems) please describe your Problem.